# Router having PPPoE connection errors: timeout waiting for PADO packets

Tags: networking, router, pppoe

I've got an Asus RT-AC66U connected to a SmartRG 505n in bridge mode.  For the last year, this setup has been fairly stable.  However, my router has recently started dropping the connection and having trouble re-establishing a new connection.  When I look at the log file, I see a significant number of these types of error messages:

```
Jul 31 20:27:20 pppd[394]: Timeout waiting for PADO packets
Jul 31 20:28:35 pppd[394]: Timeout waiting for PADO packets
Jul 31 20:29:50 pppd[394]: Timeout waiting for PADO packets
Jul 31 20:31:05 pppd[394]: Timeout waiting for PADO packets
Jul 31 20:32:20 pppd[394]: Timeout waiting for PADO packets
Jul 31 20:33:35 pppd[394]: Timeout waiting for PADO packets
Jul 31 20:34:50 pppd[394]: Timeout waiting for PADO packets
Jul 31 20:36:05 pppd[394]: Timeout waiting for PADO packets
Jul 31 20:37:20 pppd[394]: Timeout waiting for PADO packets
```

However, if I plug my PC into the modem directly (bypassing the router), I can easily establish a PPPoE connection from there.

What does this mean?  From what I've read PADO packets are upstream problems - nothing related to my equipment.  So why does a PC connection seem to work more reliably?

Comment: It's an interesting question, I think the pad0 timeout is related to lockout attempts to sign back in via ppoe when it drops. It sounds like it may be a line problem to me. Does your modem have signal to noise ratios listed in the web gui?

Comment: Did u ever solve this? I'm facing the exact same issue...

Comment: @kstratis Unfortunately, still no idea why it worked better from the PC than the router.  It still happens time-to-time, and haven't figure out why yet.  Eventually the PADO packet error clears up, but not sure if it is the way the Asus route has implemented the PPPoE protocol, or if it is a linux vs windows vs osx implementation that differs.